# Java code to display an Image in Google App Engine

Tags: java, image, google-app-engine

I have an image in the blobstore of my GAE . I need to retrieve it and make some trasformations and finally display it in my jsp page.

Currently I used,

```
BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(req.getParameter("blob-key"));
blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, res);
```

This shows the picture but I want to retrieve it as an 'Image' type and resize it using the code below

```
  ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
  Image oldImage = ImagesServiceFactory.makeImageFromBlob(blobKey);
  Transform resize = ImagesServiceFactory.makeResize(200, 300);
  Image newImage = imagesService.applyTransform(resize, oldImage);
  byte[] newImageData = newImage.getImageData();
```

How will I display my 'newImage' in a jsp page? It would be very helpful if I could see an example code. I would also like to know if there is any way i can get the blob-key of the images I presently have in my blobviewer.

Answer (score 2):

You should not process the image in the request for your JSP page. 
You have to take two steps:

1.
Render a JSP page that contains an image tag like

```
<img src="mydomain.com/getImage?blob-key=123435"/>
```

2.
Have a separate servelt mapped to mydomain.com/getImage that outputs the image with the given id.

So all the code you presented above will go in the servlet that delivers the image and not in the JSP delivering code. And then the image can be delivered using the HTTPResponses OutputStream. And don't forget to set the correct content type and length for the response.